# How to show desktop by minimize all the windows with current application in mac

Tags: objective-c

I want to show desktop on button click ,for that i have used 
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] hideOtherApplications]; 
this is working it is showing desktop also but it is not hiding the application through which we are running the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (NSWindow *win in [NSApp windows]) {
        [NSApp hide:win];
    }
```

**Edit**

This code does not hide xcode properly but it works fine under Finder:

```
NSArray *apps = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]];
    for (NSRunningApplication *app in apps ) {
        [app hide];
    }
for (NSWindow *win in [NSApp windows]) {
            [NSApp hide:win];
        }
```

Comment: It is closing the current application

Comment: But not closing the other applications running